# Automation server can't create object error while using new ActiveXObject("Msxml.DOMDocument") in IE9

Tags: dom, internet-explorer-9, activexobject

I am using **new ActiveXObject("Msxml.DOMDocument")** and I am getting "**Automation server can't create object**" error.

I am using the same code in my machine windows 7 and IE 9, and it is working fine. But with IE 9 on other machine using windows 7 I am getting this error mentioned above.

I have enabled **Initializing and Script ActiveX controls not marked as safe** and it is working fine now.

But my question is, why is it working in other machines even though that is disabled? Can you please provide me the answer?

Answer (score 0):

That machine could have a currpted file/object. You could try to replace it from the other machine and see. hope this helps.